# Error with webservices springboot

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot, cxf

I have got an error with creating webservice from wsdl.

I have already configred a maven plugin

```
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
```

for creation of java classes.

In my wsdl I have got reference to **swaref.xsd**

```
<xs:import namespace="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/xsd" schemaLocation="swaref.xsd"/>
```

When I launch springBoot app, I have got the following error:

[image]

Have you got any idea what's wrong? Maybe with apache cxf ?

Comment: Error says there is a xsd reference missing. You can check if the xsd is in-place.

Comment: I have already fixed it. I have added definition from xsd to wsdl. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if swaref.xsd exists along with the wsdl-file in the same location
2. Check if swaref.xsd contains the same namespace http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/xsd, as referenced in wsdl-file
3. Check if swaref.xsd is a valid xml, then is a valid schema file.